# How to make an existing WordPress theme responsive?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a website and i have applied a WordPress theme to it. But it is not responsive and doesn't view properly on mobile and other handle held devices. So is there any way to make an existing applied theme responsive ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is, but it's likely to be a lot of work. There is no magic solution to this. I'd suggest looking in the first couple of results when Googling `make wordpress theme responsive`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can make it responsive.

But, it can be a little bit of work. You are retrofitting an existing building.

Here are some things I am doing:

**Set up CSS breakpoints**

See more here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ > This basically sets up the ability to change the CSS at different screen widths that correspond to different device screen widths.

Basically you can do a ton of magic to the existing layout/appearance of a site, just by modifying the CSS.

Along with modifying layout, you could pull out fancy CSS3 stuff (decoration) from the basic stylesheet, only showing it at larger sizes.

There's a lot more that could be said about this. CSS is an art.

You can use the Responsive Page Tester plugin—this is really cool: http://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-page-tester/

**Make images responsive**

Okay, there's been a ton of talk about this over the past few years—but this seems to work fo r me. Use http://responsiveimg.com/ (is there a WP plugin that uses this yet? Not sure.) You could take a look at http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-responsive-images/ . I like http://responsiveimg.com/ because I can *see* that it really replaces the bloody images with the proper size.

You need to concern yourself not just with the *appearance*, but the page weight, as well.

If you need to *change* the image sizes to match the breakpoints you desire, you need to rebuild the images. This plugin is wonderful for both rebuilding images, and setting the sizes: http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/

**Selectively Hide or Show stuff**

You could use this plugin, that lets you use shortcodes to hide or show things for mobile/desktop: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/ . If you are more technical, loading this plugin lets you use https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/, and you can access all the functions there. (See http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1392). Anyway, if you use the functions, you can hide/show at the template level, not just the edit window level.

**Convert the menu to a mobile-friendly one at mobile sizes**

At a certain breakpiont, you need to collapse the menu. This paid one might work for you: http://labs.sevenspark.com/UberMenu . You could also try this one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-select-menu/ . It's pretty darn nice.

**Resizing videos**

Here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/fitvids-for-wordpress/

**Or, just serve a different theme altogether**

WP Touch Pro is great — http://www.bravenewcode.com/wptouch/ . It has a tone of great defaults.

Pros:

- Start from a mobile "scratch," instead of trying to retrofit a potentially heavy desktop site into your mobile
- Fit in just the changes you need
- Take advantage of a lot of mobile code and design that's been done for you

Cons:

- It may have a totally different "look" than your current site
- Custom features such as custom post types or special theme code will not be there, and would have to be recreated or left out

Answer (score 0):

If the theme is not 'responsive' then there is no switch to make it responsive.

To make a theme 'responsive' requires general knowledge about what makes a theme responsive.

In general, a theme is classed as **responsive** if the format of the page can adapt according to the viewing window it has been given. This is either through a user resizing the browser, or the user viewing the page on different sized devices such as mobile phones.

To understand how to implement this in a general sense, and specifically for WordPress, would require a more specific question.

To make any changes to a WordPress theme, first you must learn about the WordPress theme structure, and **WordPress Template Hierarchy**.

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your help, i went through some articles and decided to customize a theme with bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 0):

One simple suggestion for making WordPress theme responsive:

First you may found out some responsive WordPress theme that matches your existing theme and then you may improve some changes that affected your look n feel due to application of new theme.

This is the first solution that you may try since it is simple than the second one. If it doesn't work out for you then you may proceed to change the CSS so as to make it responsive by creating a child theme.